# jQuery working in everything but IE? (UI)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, user-interface

I'm using jQuery and jQuery UI for the animation effects.

You can see here in the jsfiddle it works in every other browser bar any version of IE, including 10. Now I'm a bit new to Javascript, so I know there will be some flaws with this fiddle, but, here it is:

http://jsfiddle.net/BqqMD/2/

Why is it when in IE, it opens the panel, but positions the #closeBtn element to the left, and then when you click it, it doesn't close the .panel class?

I'm totally baffled, but I know my code is messy here, so I was hoping for some heads up on how this can be resolved.

Here's the JS code:

```
var panel     = ".panel";
var menuBtn   = "#menuBtn";
var closeBtn  = "#closeBtn";
var panelTime = 1000;
var btnTime   = 300;
var animDir   = 'Right';

$(function 
    MenuOptions(){
        $(panel).hide();

            $(menuBtn).click(function(){
                $(menuBtn).hide('slide', {direction: animDir}, btnTime);
                $(panel).show('slide', {direction: animDir}, panelTime);        
                $(closeBtn).show('slide', {direction: animDir}, btnTime);
                });
        $(closeBtn).click(function(){
            $(this).hide('slide', {direction: animDir}, btnTime);
            $(panel).hide('slide', {direction: animDir}, panelTime);    
            $(menuBtn).show('slide', {direction: animDir}, btnTime);
     });

});
```

Many regards.

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between IE9 on Windows and Chrome on Linux.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin you're right. I just tested it on browserstack and it's fine, but when using IE10 including the compatibility mode, it won't display properly.

Comment: If you have any console.log() statements in your js code, it will kill IE displaying things and sometimes it won't run your script at all.

Comment: your fiddle is working fine for me in IE 9

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works like a charm for me in IE9.

you better reset the IE and run again.